# How do i get the Original create class dialogue in android studio

Tags: android, class, dialog

I am using 4.0 and i get this new dialogue box ( shown in picture) when creating a class
how do i go back the previous one ?

how do I use the previous dialogue in which I could extend classes select type  etc.

this is the standard one i wish to use from the android developers website
[https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWgvJ.png)

I tried resetting  the default setting but it does not seem to work.

[screenshot of the new dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f8Kn.png)